# Ho to configure Junit4 AndroidStudio with Gradle

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, junit4, build.gradle

I want to make test of some clases in my project.

I'm project is all android, but the new clases are pure Java (I'm trying to make a little sdk for the app)

But I don't know how to configure correctly

**Gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19"
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 28
        versionName "4.0.5"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
                        ..........
        }

        release {
                        ..........
        }

    }

    buildTypes {

        debug{
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_ENABLED", "true"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
            buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_ENABLED", "false"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    productFlavors{
        develFlavor{

        }

        testFlavor{
            ..........
        }

        trainingFlavor{
            ..........
        }

        preFlavor{
            ..........
        }

        proFlavor{
            .........
        }
    }

}

if (project.hasProperty('storePassword')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = storePassword
}

if (project.hasProperty('keyAlias')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = keyAlias
}

if (project.hasProperty('keyPassword')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keyPassword
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        java.srcDir file(''src/main/java/es/tempos/gas/sdk/test'')
    }
}

dependencies {
    unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/sbc_mapslib.jar')
    compile files('libs/t21c2dm-lib-v1.0.jar')
}
```

I want to put the test cases in the folfer Test>SDK

**Estructure of the app:**

```
+SmartPhoneGreatApp
----.idea
----app
    -----build
    -----libs
    -----src
         -----develFlavor
         -----main
              ----sdk
         -----preFlavor
         ----- .........
         ........
    -----test
         ------sdk
```

**and the testing class**(for the moment do nothing)

```
package es.tempos21.gas.sdk.test;

import org.junit.Test;


public class AuthenticateTest {


    @Test
    public void testAuthenticate() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

**And the error I'm getting:**

```
Gradle 'SmartPhoneGreatApp' project refresh failed:
         Could not find property 'unitTest' on SourceSet container.
         Gradle settings
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Android plugin, sourceSets are configured differently from how the Java plugin does it, so you should read the docs at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies

For testing you'll want to do something like this:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

A shortcut would be to do this instead:

```
android.sourceSets.androidTest.setRoot('tests')
```

Note that you're supplying a new top-level directory for where the tests go (and the Java classes will be in a directory structure underneath that corresponds to their package path); in your example you're trying to point it at a package already inside **src/main/java/path/to/package**, which isn't going to work.